# What javascript library is best for plotting line chart with many series having low amount of points each

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I need to plot 60 (more in the future) series of 25 points on a single plot onto the HTML page. Whole plot should be zoomable and filterable (user should be able to i. e. hide all series except the one selected or to hide only one series selected).

Somebody knows the javascript chart library which best suited for such a task? Current implementation works on Highcharts and it chokes on "hide all series except one selected" feature.

Maybe I can just stick with Highcharts, but I really need a way to *quickly* hide all series except the one clicked on.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, guys, I found the acceptable solution myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry, I've upvoted all of your answers but I was fully content with my own solution.

Disabling the auto-updating of scale on Highcharts made the needed increase in perfomance:

```
new Highcharts.Charts({
    chart: {
        ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
        reflow: false
    }
});
```

This way hiding/showing the series work acceptable. It's just that all other functions of Highcharts completely satisfy me.

The mass hiding/showing of series itself is not so important, I was interested only in increase of perfomance.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/).
Seems pretty nice for graphs. May be able to get it to do what you want?

If not, maybe try [Raphaël JS](http://raphaeljs.com/)  Also pretty nice for graphs, and there is the extension gRaphaël for graphs as well.

Perhaps one of those may do what you're after :)

**Edit**

I'd also throw [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) into the mix as well. I've just used it in a project and it works pretty damn well with large datasets and it's pretty flexible and expandable. Worth looking in to

Comment: Wow, Raphaeljs has graph plugin as well?..

Rickshaw halted browser on 60 lines with 25 points each.

Comment: Flot has [plugins](http://www.flotcharts.org/plugins/) which can give you features that aren't in the default Flot.

Answer (score 2):

Try [amCharts.com](http://amcharts.com)
Here is JS fiddle with your scenario implemented: jsfiddle.net/zeroin/gqtmN/
Clicking on legend entry hides all graphs and shows the one you clicked.

And the source code, as SO requested:

```
var chart;

var chart;
var chartData = [];


function generateChartData() {
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 60);

    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

        var obj = {
            date: newDate
        };

        for (var j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
            obj["val" + j] = Math.round(Math.random() * (j + 1) * 10);
        }
        chartData.push(obj);
    }
}

AmCharts.ready(function() {

    generateChartData();

    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.marginTop = 0;
    chart.autoMarginOffset = 5;
    chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/";
    chart.zoomOutButton = {
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        backgroundAlpha: 0.15
    };
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "date";

    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
    categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
    categoryAxis.dashLength = 2;
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15;
    categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";


    for (var j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.title = "series " + j;
        graph.valueField = "val" + j;
        graph.hidden = true;
        chart.addGraph(graph);
    }

    chart.graphs[0].hidden = false;

    var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
    chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
    chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

    var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
    chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.addListener("showItem", handleAll);

    chart.addLegend(legend);
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});


function handleAll(event) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
        chart.graphs[j].hidden = true;
    }

    event.dataItem.hidden = false;
    chart.validateNow();
}​
```

Disclaimer: I am author of amCharts.

Answer (score 1):

[teechart](/questions/tagged/teechart) HTML5 Charting Javascript allows hidding series setting their "visible" property to false.  You can use the series onclick event to hide all the other series except the clicked one, for example:

```
Chart1.series.each(function(series) { series.onclick=clickedSeries; });

function clickedSeries(series, point) {
  Chart1.series.each(function(s) { s.visible = (s === series) });
  Chart1.draw();
}
```

There's a full online demo here:

http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2012.12.14.1.4/demos/

regards
david berneda
www.teechart.com